# What a pluperfect a##hole

Tags: etymology, american-english, history

From *The Silence of the Lambs* (1988):

> "Marilyn Sutter saw it upstairs. Chilton was blowing off about "The Search for Billy
> Rubin." Then he went to dinner with a television reporter. That's where he was when
> Lecter took a walk. *What a **pluperfect** asshole*."

While I am aware of the pluperfect *tense*, the above usage of the word strikes me as rather exotic. ODO only lists the grammatical definition in its [British English reference](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pluperfect). But it provides an additional definition under its [American English entry](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/pluperfect):

> [as modifier] more than perfect:
>
> *they have **one pluperfect daughter** and are expecting an ideal little brother for her*

[Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pluperfect) defines its alternate sense as *utterly perfect or complete* along with a note on its origin:

> late 15th century: from modern Latin **plusperfectum**, from Latin (tempus praeteritum) plus quam perfectum

I'm curious as to how this odd-sounding construction made its way from the grammar book into common parlance. Is it used in this sense only in the US? Is it still in use?

(Although I see it used in other languages, I believe that *pluperfect* is no longer the term of choice in English grammar.)

Comment: If your question is how pluperfect made it in to common parlance - I don't think it has. This is not common usage, just authorial choice.

Comment: @MarkBeadles This sense is noted in every dictionary that I've checked thus far. Also, as you can infer from the excerpt, it is used in colloquial dialogue.

Comment: Interesting! I wasn't aware it was being used that way very often. Fair enough - now I'm curious, too.

Comment: I think it is a reasonable -literal- rendering of the word, and so not unlikely for writers to be a little creative and use it so (without having any prior cultural history).

Comment: What @Mitch said. OED notwithstanding, many or even *most* such usages could effectively be "coinages" by the writer at the time, since both the construction itself and the intended meaning are so obvious.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The OED's adjectival sense A2b is:

> *hyperbolically*. Utterly perfect; ideal, faultless.

And has citations from 1832 to 1992, from both US and UK sources, the last two from Noel Coward's *Diary* (1965) and *Newsweek*:

> - It was a perfect, pluperfect, evening; absolutely clear and not a breath of wind.
> - While Johnny [Carson] may have been his own best guest, he was also the pluperfect guest.

---

Sense A3 is:

> *colloq*. As a general intensifier.

With citations from 1889 to 2000, all from the US, the last from *Play World*:

> The pleasure of living fully, including the alternative to unbutton and raise pluperfect hell.

---

There's also the obsolete sense A2a, with 1802 and 1856 citations from British magazines:

> Having or being more than what is needed; superfluous. *Obs.*