# What is the etymological justification for taking the grammatical term "pluperfect" and turning it into an adjective meaning 'more than perfect"?

Tags: word-usage

I'm interested in the usage of the word *pluperfect* in the following passage from Thomas Harris’s crime thriller, *The Silence of the Lambs*.

Jerry Burroughs of the National Crime Information Center makes a comment to Jack Crawford, an FBI special agent, regarding Dr. Frederick Chilton, the administrator of the Baltimore State Hospital for the Criminally Insane:

> “Chilton was blowing off about “The Search for Billy Rubin.” Then he
>   went to dinner with a television reporter. That’s where he was when
>   (Hannibal) Lector took a walk. What a **pluperfect** asshole.” - Page
>   272.

Though several online dictionaries define *pluperfect* only as a grammatical term equivalent to “past perfect tense”, *Readers-Plus English-Japanese Dictionary* defines it as

> 1. (grammar) n.a. past perfect. 2.(slang) a. perfect, extraordinary.

I’m curious to know how the slang usage of *pluperfect* to mean “perfect, extraordinary” came about. What is the etymological background for the appropriation of the grammatical term to this slangy use? Is it common to use the word like this?

Comment: Dear Yoichi, [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/88204) seems to have been asked before, including with that same citation. I would ask you to decide for yourself, since you are the asker, whether you feel that Hugo’s answer there covers all the nuances you would like explained. It may, and it may not.

Comment: For me it's just like "penultimate".  Often today people use that word totally incorrectly.  (The fact that the "silly" meaning of pluperfect has made its way in to some dictionaries, is just sad.)  For me, the quote in the book just looks silly - as silly as someone using "penultimate" to mean "awesome".

Comment: @tchrist. I wasn't aware of the duplication of my question with the previous post by Coleopterist, and am surprised to find Coleopterist has noted and cited the same passage in the same work of the late 1980, "The Silence of Lambs" now. What a coincidence! I don't mind closure of this question. But my quetion still remains (1) why this word was deverged into two different meaning and usages which are 'pluperfect' irrelevant. (2) Is this usage very common as used by the author in a million seller book, and noticed by separate EL&U users concurrently?

Comment: @Yoichi The reason it has both meanings is simply its etymology: _perfect_ historically means ‘completely done’ and is used as the name for a (Latin) verbal aspect. _Pluperfect_ is a contracted form of Latin _plus quam perfectum_ meaning ‘more than perfect’ (lit. ‘more than completely done’). The perfect aspect lies back in time, but the pluperfect lies even further back, so it’s ‘more than perfect’; similarly, if something is absolutely without flaw, you can say that it’s ‘more than perfect’. This latter usage is not common at all—there’d probably not be two ELU questions about it then. :-)

Answer (score 1):

It's a rarely used word that sounds quite like an intensifier of a commonly used word, so it's easy to misuse it --easy enough so that it could become an actual alternate meaning.  I would venture it's close to the incorrect but common use of *penultimate* to mean "better than best."

Comment: Chris. I understand, but isn't it a bit awkward to rephrase "He is a pluperfect ass hole" as "He is better than best ass hole," when we comment on someone?

Comment: @Yoichi _Perfect_ doesn't mean ‘best’ here, it just means ‘complete, through and through’. You can say that someone is a perfect gentleman, or indeed a perfect asshole—in both cases, it just means that they are _entirely_ a gentleman/asshole. If they're even beyond that, then they are a _pluperfect_ gentleman/asshole.

Comment: For me it's a ridiculous use of a Latin term.

Answer (score -1):

A "pluperfect" tense construction is a *high-level* construction. So a "pluperfect" a-hole, is a *high level* a-hole.

The word "pluperfect" itself means ["more than perfect."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluperfect)